# Linear programming converting standard into standard form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Hi I am trying to understand Linear Programming and are trying to solve the exercises in the book Introduction To Algorithms by Cormen, Rivest, Stein I am comparing my solutions with solutions online. For the problem [29.1-4](https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap29/29.1/) I don't understand how and if they need x3 as a variable that is *nonnegative*. Furthermore I would supsect that their solution is wrong considering that the variables they introduce are: `x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 =< 0` but shouldn't they have been `>=` considering that we want non-negativity?
Considering that the book is really scarce when describing how to, could someone show what a good solution would look like?

**EDIT**

As requrested in the comments here is a the definition of standard from according to the book mentioned in which the exercises also occurs, in which a LP that is not in standard form is characterized by:

> 1. The objective function might be a minimization rather than a maximization.
> 2. There might be variables without nonnegativity constraints.
> 3. There might be equality constraints, which have an equal sign rather than a less-than-or-equal-to sign.
> 4. There might be inequality constraints, but instead of having a less-than-or-equal-to sign, they have a greater-than-or-equal-to sign.

The book then describes how to avoid each of these by conversion, but I figure that this wouldn't be necessary to point out possible mistakes of the referenced solution, nor to suggest a correct solution.

Comment: There do appear to be some errors in the given solution, but the source material does not define "standard form" so it is unclear as to what the correct solution should be.

Comment: Yes. I think that the book mentioned does define standard form, so it would probably be based on that, that the correct solution should be derived.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide said definition in the question, for context.

Comment: Alright I shall see if I can provide it in a readible and true-to-the-source sort of way.

Comment: Ok, I now think I found a way to provide a definition that you can use.